# jQuery Datatables - Date searching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am working on a asp.net core 3.1 mvc web app, I have a jquery datatable. I use individual column searching in footer of table.

One of my tables columns is date.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCreateDate))
            {
                var searchDate = DateTime.Parse(searchCreateDate);
               jData = (IOrderedQueryable<JData>)jData.Where(m => m.CreateDate.Date >= searchDate);

            }
```

I want it to find dates that are greater than the date entered in the search box. This code block works correctly if I write all the date at once. Typing the whole date at once means that copying this date and pasting it into the search box.

If I try to type the date in the search box, it instantly checks and gives an error. For example, I want to type 2021-02-05 in the search box but as soon as I type 2 it throws the following error: System.FormatException: 'String' 2 'was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can I edit this search to start after I have finished the search box? Or like search after I press the Enter.

Comment: You mean like an example on how to use [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0)?
or using a [condition on js](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchBuilder.conditions%5Btype%5D%5Bcond%5D.isInputValid)?

Comment: Actually, searching starts when I starting to enter the date in the search box, but I want the search to start after I'm done typing the date.

Comment: Are you referring to the DataTables global search box, or a custom search box specifically for entering your date? The global search box has several events attached to it, including `keyup`, which causes this "instant" searching. If you can describe a bit more about how your search input is built, that may make it easier to suggest how to alter the behavior. Can you [edit] the question?

Comment: I mentioned about individual column searching @andrewjames

Comment: OK - thanks, and sorry I missed that. Are you using a solution based on [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html), or something similar? If so, then you can change the `'keyup change clear'` events shown in the example to be `change` (or some other suitable event). Then, the logic will only be executed when you leave the input field.